# SQL: How to join two select query

Tags: sql

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity
1                10248    11          12
2                10248    42          10
3                10248    72           5
4                10249    14           9
5                10249    51          40
```

I want to sum all the quantity for each OrderID and after that i need to total up all quantity. 
I able to create to different query as

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity) over ()AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM OrderDetails
where OrderID in ('10248','10249')
group by OrderID;
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) over ()AS TotalItemsOrdered
FROM OrderDetails
where OrderID in ('10248','10249');
```

but i want to join both query to display as same result. Please teach me how i can join both query and display at same result.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want that format... the usual way to have totals by group and then a grand total is with `GROUP BY ROLLUP` - which should exist in most database products.

Using Oracle syntax below:

```
with inputs ( OrderDetailID, OrderID, ProductID, Quantity ) as (
       select 1, 10248, 11, 12 from dual union all
       select 2, 10248, 42, 10 from dual union all
       select 3, 10248, 72,  5 from dual union all
       select 4, 10249, 14,  9 from dual union all
       select 5, 10249, 51, 40 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select   case grouping_id(orderid) when 1 then 'TOTAL' 
                                   else to_char(orderid) end as orderid,
         sum(quantity) as total_quantity
from     inputs
where    orderid in (10248, 10249)  --  assuming orderid is NUMBER, not VARCHAR
group by rollup (orderid)
order by orderid
;

ORDERID  TOTAL_QUANTITY
-------  --------------
10248                27
10249                49
TOTAL                76
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity) as OrderQuantity,
       SUM(SUM(Quantity)) OVER () as TotalItemsOrdered
FROM OrderDetails
WHEER OrderID in ('10248','10249')
GROUP BY OrderID;
```